# Quit Jmeter after tests and save aggregate reports

Tags: jmeter, report, aggregate, jmeter-plugins

Yesterday due to some reason my Jmeter Machine crashed and I do not have results.

These results run overnight on a laptop, what I am looking for is, I can quit Jmeter ones tests are done and my reports get saved automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Given you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

> jmeter -n -t /your/script.jmx -l **/test/results.jtl**

JMeter should store test execution results in the `results.jtl` file. When the test is finished you will be able to open the file with the Listener of your choice using "Browse" button and analyze the results.

Even in that case you can loose some data in case of JVM crash, by default JMeter doesn't store each single result, it periodically flushes results data. You can add the next line to *user.properties* file in order to tell JMeter to store each single result immediately (JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

Alternative way is passing the property via `-J` command-line argument like:

> jmeter **-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true** -n -t /your/script.jmx -l /test/results.jtl

See [Listeners > Default Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) to learn more about JMeter defaults, what properties are available and what can be changed to make results to look accordingly to your requirements

Comment: Is it possible in GUI mode too? Any plugin or OOTB?

Comment: You can do it by adding a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), for example [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report), select metrics you would like to store and set result file in the "Write results to file / Read from file" input - JMeter will store results in that file. But be aware that [listeners are very resource intensive](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) and they may ruin your test, I would recommend going for non-GUI mode instead.

Answer (score 0):

Run the JMeter always in [Non-GUI](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) mode.

Following is the command:

```
jmeter.bat -n -t Sctipt.jmx -l results.jtl
```

`-l` : option to save the results.

When the test is completed, automatically results will be saved in `results.jtl` file. you can give full path also, otherwise, saves the file in current directory i.e., JMeter folder where 'jmeter.bat' file present.

Don't keep any listeners in the script as they utilizes system resources.